# match-3 Board border

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, gui, graphic-effects

I'm new to unity and I'm currently working on a match-3 game.
I know there are a lot of similar games and that's why I would like to know what is the best way to autogenerate border of a match-3 board game ?
Till now I have tile with game pieces but I would like to make unity to autogenerate (select from a pack of images/sprites) board borders as you can see on the image below (it is an example):
[image]

My board is not necessary a rectangle or a square and its size is generated from the inspector of "board" game object.

Comment: You may be able to implement this with a [Sprite Shape](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.spriteshape@3.0/manual/index.html) or a [Tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html).

Comment: I understood that 2D sprite shapes are only deformation/transform effect of a 2d tile. While the Tile should be ok on a different Z (pushed it back as background). However, I would like to know if there are some example on internet ?

Comment: "only deformation/transform effect" ...which would allow you to deform a coloured stripe or other simple border graphic around the curved shape of your perimeter. "are some examples on internet" — you have access to the same search engines we do.

Comment: Are you talking about the Tile of the 2dSprite shape ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. If you've tried this and gotten stuck somewhere, try editing your question to show what you tried and where you're stuck or what specific help you need.